# React query triggered multiple times in onError and onSuccess

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have encapsulated the useUser hook using React Query and I'm using it in multiple places. However, I have encountered an issue where onSuccess and onError callbacks are being triggered multiple times. How can I prevent this behavior?

```
export const useUser = () => {
  return useQuery<User>(['userData'], () => API.fetchUserData(), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log('many times')
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log('many times')
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how callbacks on useQuery are working - they run for each usage - similar to how `useEffect` runs in every invocation of your custom hook.

That's one of the reasons why we have deprecated the callbacks (onSuccess, onError and onSettled) on useQuery and will remove them in the next major version.

If you want one-time logging per Query, have a look at the [global callbacks of the QueryCache](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryCache#global-callbacks).

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log('one time')
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log('one time')
    }
})
```

You can find more info on why the callbacks are bad and what to do instead [in my blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose). There's also some discussion going on in the [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5279).